# How to disable jquery code in partial view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I use this code for edit :

I want to disable dropdownlist, when radioobutton is selected, it not working in `Edit` Partial view but it work in insert partial. Insert partial code is exactly Same as Edit Partial View .

what's the problem ?

Partial View :

```
    @model Amene.Areas.Admin.Models.CategoryViewModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", Url = "/Admin/Category/Edit", OnSuccess = "InsertCategory" }))
            {
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <input class="form-control col-md-6 col-lg-6" name="CategoryName" value="@Model.CategoryModel.CategoryName" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <label class="radio-inline"><input value="0" type="radio" id="main" name="MainCat" @(Model.CategoryModel.ParentID == 0 ? Html.Raw("checked='checked'") : Html.Raw(""))>دسته اصلی</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input value="1" type="radio" id="sub" name="MainCat" @(Model.CategoryModel.ParentID != 0 ? Html.Raw("checked='checked'") : Html.Raw(""))>زیر دسته</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4" id="parentcontent">
        <select name="ParentID" id="dropdowncat">
            @foreach (var item in Model.List)
                {
                <option value="@item.CatID" @(Model.CategoryModel.ParentID == item.CatID ? Html.Raw("selected='selected'") : Html.Raw(""))>@item.CategoryName</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CategoryModel.CatID)
    <input type="submit" value="ثبت" />
}
```

Contoller :

```
public PartialViewResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var model = new CategoryViewModel();
        var cat = _CategoryService.CategoryByID(id);
        model.CategoryModel = Mapper.Map<CategoryModel>(cat);
        var categorymodel = _CategoryService.GetAllCategory();
        model.List = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CategoryModel>>(categorymodel);
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

Scripts :

```
$("#main").click(function () {
        $("#dropdowncat").attr("disabled", true);
    });

    $("#sub").click(function () {
        $("#dropdowncat").attr("disabled", false);
    });
```

and in View :

```
        <div id="insertcat">
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi @Kianoush see this [link](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 0):

for code to work on dynamic content it has to be tied to the document.  change your click events to

```
$(document).on('click', '#main', function(){...
```

Comment: Can You Write Code For Me Please ?

Comment: that is code.  just change the structure of your click event to match mine and it will work

Comment: what does "it not work" mean?  did you get an error?  can you give some details as to what you are seeing?